# Purpose for extended real number line (Rudin RCA)

Tags: calculus

Theorem 1.12:
Suppose M is a $\sigma$-algebra in X, and Y is a topological space.
Let *f* map X into Y.

(c) If Y = [-$\infty$, $\infty$] and $f^{-1}$(($\alpha$, $\infty$]) $\in$ M for every real $\alpha$, then *f* is measurable.

To prove (c), let $\Omega$ be the collection of all E $\subseteq$ [ -$\infty$, $\infty$] such that
$f^{-1}$(E) $\in$ M. Choose a real number $\alpha$, and choose $\alpha$$_n$ < $\alpha$ so that $\alpha$$_n$ $\to$ $\alpha$ as
n $\to$ $\infty$. Since ($\alpha$$_n$, $\infty$] $\in$ n for each n, since
$$[-\infty, \alpha) = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} [-\infty, \alpha_n] = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (\alpha_n, \infty]^c$$
and since (a) shows that $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we see that [-$\infty, \alpha) \in \Omega$. The same is then true of 
$$(\alpha, \beta) = [-\infty, \beta) \cap (\alpha, \infty].$$
Since every open set in [-$ \infty, \infty$] is a countable union of segments of the
above types, $\Omega$ contains every open set. Thus *f* is measurable.

Theorem 1.14 then uses this to show that the supremum of a sequence of measurable extended-real functions is also measurable.

My question is that if we used non-extended real numbers $(-\infty, \infty)$, would it make a difference to the above theorems? Or is it more relevant to the rest of the book?

Comment: It is a convenience otherwise you need lots of special cases.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Would you mind giving 1 or 2 examples of these special cases?

Comment: Well, if you have a map $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$, then in particular, you have a map $\overline{f}: X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ (simply compose $f$ with the inclusion if you want to be formal). Similarly if the co-domain of $f$ were $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ and so on. The point of only having the above theorem is that $f$ is measurable if and only if $\overline{f}$ is measurable. Otherwise, you'd need separate theorems for maps into the reals, the extended reals and the reals extended by only one infinity.

Comment: That clarified my doubts perfectly. Thanks!